# How to configure DI services available to the Startup class constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

When I create the webhost for an ASP.NET Core application I can specify the `Startup` class but not an instance.

The constructor of your own Startup class can take parameter which are provided through DI. I know how to register services for DI within `ConfigureServices` but as that is a member of that class these services are not available for the constructor of my startup class.

How do I register services which will be available as constructor parameter of the Startup class?

The reason is that I have to supply an object instance which must be created outside/before the webhost is created and I do not want to pass it in a *global-like* style.

Code to create the IWebHost:

```
this.host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup<WebStartup>()
log.Debug("Run webhost");
this.host.Start();
```

Constructor of `WebStartup`:

```
public WebStartup(IHostingEnvironment env, MyClass myClass)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();
    ...
}
```

So specifically, how to I register `MyClass` in this example (which obviously must be done before `WebStartup` is instanciated by the `IWebHost`)?

Answer (score 9):

Although Steven's concerns are valid and you should take note of them, it is technically possible to configure the DI container that is used to resolve your Startup class.

ASP.NET hosting uses dependency injection to wire up an instance of your Startup class and also let us add our own services to that container using the `ConfigureServices` extension method on `IWebHostBuilder`:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>())
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

and:

```
public Startup(IMyService myService)
{
    myService.Test();
}
```

In fact, all that `UseStartup<WebStartup>` does is adding it as a service implementation of `IStartup` to the hosting DI container ([see this](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L56)).

Please note that instances of your services will be resolved again in the *application* container as a new instance of the `IServiceProvider` will be built. The registration of the services will, however, be passed to the application `IServiceCollection` in your Startup class.

Comment: You are right about ASP.NET having 2 internal containers, but are wrong about having to reconfigure them again. The registered `IMyService` will be available in the application container as well. Problem however is that by building 2 container instances, ASP.NET introduces the problem of a [Torn Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.org/diatl), because when that `IMyService` is resolved again later on, a new instance is created (since there will be a singleton per container). Reconfiguring that instance in the container will not solve the issue, because you'll still end up with two instances.

Comment: @Steven you're right. I mixed the part about registration of services and instances of services being created. Thanks for heads up, I'll update my answer.

Comment: As I register a singleton instance and do not re-register it inside `WebStartup.ConfigureServices` there should not be a torn lifecycle to my understanding. Thanks for pointing me to the `WebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices` - I misunderstand it would replace `WebStartup.ConfigureServices` but it works as explained by you, Henk!

Comment: @ZoolWay: My advise it to not use auto-wiring in the `WebHostBuilder` (i.e. refrain from using one of the `AddXXX<TService, TImplementation>()` method calls). The only safe method to use is the `AddSingleton<T>(T)` overload. In other words, create your class by hand, e.g.: `services.AddSingleton<IMyService>(new MyService());`. This will prevent any future problems such as Torn lifestyles, captive dependencies and other hard to track problems.

Comment: @Steven Yes, that was my thought. But the most *right-thing-to-do* solution would be to use a DI-framework, set it up before ASP.NET Core and then use its adopter to continue the same DI-framework within ASP.NET core - would you agree?

Comment: @ZoolWay: I *disagree*. You will often be unable to setup your own container at that stage in the pipeline. Further more, I would even suggest keeping application components [separated](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2016/07/working-around-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) (i.e. in its own container) from framework components.

Comment: Thanks @Steven - I see the point in separating app and framework containers. Your links and some related directed my to some good thoughts about DI.

Answer (score 7):

This is a 'chicken or the egg' problem: You can't let the DI container resolve an object graph before it is configured.

Your problem however should not exist, because just as you should strictly separate the registration phase of the container from the resolve-phase (as ASP.NET Core enforces upon you), the same way should you separate the registration phase from the phase before that where you load configuration values.

What this means is that classes that you require during the registration phase of the container should *not* be resolved by the container. because that could lead to [common problems](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decisions.html#container-is-locked) that are hard to track down.

Instead you should create the class by hand. For instance:

```
public class Startup
{
    private static MyDependency dependency;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        dependency = new MyDependency();
        var instance = new MyClass(dependency);

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(instance.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register the dependency if it is required by other components.
        services.AddSingleton<MyDependency>(dependency);

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I cannot create the `MyDependency` instance within `Startup`, it must be created before as it needs information not available inside `Startup`. Passing it through some kind of global would be possible but as the documentation says the constructor of `Startup` can make use of DI if felt that it would be a better approach to use it.

Comment: @ZoolWay: Please update your question with this specific information of your exact use case; without this specific information it is impossible to give concrete feedback on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance of `MyClass` called `myClass` and you need to inject that instance into your `Startup` class. I had a similar requirement and after some experimentation I came up with the following.

First, we inject the `myClass` *instance* **before** we call `UseStartup`:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    // .... other code
    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton(myClass)) // Inject myClass instance
    .UseStartup<WebStartup>()
```

Now we need to get hold of the object in `Startup` (`WebStartup` in your case). I wasn't able to find a way to access it from the constructor, but that shouldn't matter as it can be accessed from within the startup class' `ConfigureServices()` and, if necessary, saved to a field or property from there if it need to be made available to `Startup.Configure()` which is called later. Here is what I came up with:

```
    // This goes into Startup.cs/WebStartup.cs
    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var myClass = services.Single(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(MyClass)).ImplementationInstance as MyClass;
        if (myClass == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(MyClass) + " instance is null");

        // Now do all the things
    }
```

I suspect that there may be something in the Framework to retrieve the injected instance more easily, but if not - or until I find it - I can confirm that the above works perfectly!

Comment: AddSingleton is not accessible. I am working on Net core 3.1